# mysql/oracle stored math formula

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

is there any way apply math formula from stored string in Oracle and or MySQL?

```
col1 | col2 | formula
---------------------
 2   |  2   | col1*col2
 2   |  3   | col1+col2 

SELECT * from tbl

result:
col1 | col2 | formula
---------------------
 2   |  2   |   4
 2   |  3   |   5
```

edit: for each row another formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're saying is you want to have the database parse the formula string. For example, for Oracle you could

- Add a column to the table to contain the result
- Run an update statement which would call a PL/SQL function with the values of the columns in the table and the text of the formula

  update {table} set formula_result = fn_calc_result (col1, col2, formula_column);

The PL/SQL function would create a string by replacing the "col1" and "col2" and so forth with the actual values of those columns. You can do that with regular expresions, as long as the formulas are consistently written.

Then use

```
execute immediate 'select '||{formula}||' from dual' into v_return;
return v_return;
```

to calculate the result and return it.

Of course, you could also write your own parser. If you decide to go that way, don't forget to handle operation precedence, parentheses, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a virtual column.  See here for [excellent article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/VirtualColumns_11gR1.php) on its setup and use.

Answer (score 1):

you may do it via a PL/SQL script that you can trigger automcatically when inserting the data.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL

PL/SQL is a kind of program that executes in the database itself. It's quite easy to do.