# MySQL Executing string as math operation

Tags: mysql, math

In a column I have something like this:

Amount:

```
12
2x25
192
```

How is it possible to multiply in this example 2x25 to order it correctly ASC.

My starting point:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY REPLACE(Amount,'x','*') ASC
```

TIA
frgtv10

Comment: I think the question is duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100190/extract-numbers-from-a-varchar-cell-and-do-math-with-them-in-pure-mysql and you may also find this guy here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210865/mysql-oracle-stored-math-formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  SELECT 
  CAST(if(Amount LIKE '%x%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Amount, 'x', 1) *
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Amount, 'x', -1) , Amount) as  unsigned ) as amount 
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY Amount ASC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56430/17)

steps and explaining :

- locate fields with x value
- sbstring from left and right and multiply it.
- then cast the multiplication as unsigned.
- order it asc

Comment: makes my answer redundant, and ruins my attempt at education, +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

As long as this is the only formula (multiplying 2 numbers), you should be able to hard-code it with INSTR, SUBSTRING, and CONVERT.